# activeadmin with sorcery skip_filter require_login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, before-filter, sorcery

I am use sorcery for my rails app, and have:

```
before_filter :require_login
```

in my application controller

However, when I do:

```
localhost:3000/admin
```

I wish to jump straight into the activeadmin login page, rather than do the normal user login first, and then activeadmin login.

I've tried:

```
  config.skip_before_filter :require_login
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `controller { skip_before_filter :require_login }` in one of your resources? If that works, you can add skip_before_filter to the activeadmin base controller...

Comment: I have, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how do you add it to the base controller?

Comment: You basically have to monkey-patch it. Try something like this: https://gist.github.com/amiel/44ef08d0761441070540

Comment: hmm. I put it into the active_admin.rb init file(with skip_before_filter :requrie_login instead), but it doesn't seems like it

Comment: Ok, well I'm at a loss then. I don't really know sorcery (this technique works fine for me with Devise). Are you sure that your `before_filter` name is correct?

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough info. Is your code up on github where we can look at it?